# Create DocumentDB Document with child Documents without "meta-information"

Tags: .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

This has got me going in self-recursive circles for two days now.

I have a recursive ObjectModel in which i convert single Objects to `Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document`. As I use recursion, the "phone_numbers" property in the example below is a `List(Of Document)`.
How can I get rid of the `"_rid", "_self", "_ts", "_etag"` properties? For the lack of knowing what they are called, let me call them meta-properties. 
I want to either remove them before saving to the database or - even better - avoid having them generated?

**What my code generates:**

```
{
  "id": "object768f02af46b24a5c86c1e5eeaae721c6",
  "family_name": "Green",
  "given_name": "Thomas",
  "phone_numbers": [
    {
      "id": "eb8e6d6b6317499c96c568a2b6088101",
      "_rid": null,
      "_self": null,
      "_ts": 0,
      "_etag": null,
      "name": "private phone",
      "number": "564894654"
    },
    {
      "id": "e8ffb8de9d55489cb84d3342189240c1",
      "_rid": null,
      "_self": null,
      "_ts": 0,
      "_etag": null,
      "name": "work phone",
      "number": "654649684684"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the unmodified output of `Document.ToString()` before writing it to DocumentDB. I have no idea why there are no meta-tags in the root document at this point. But I don't seem to need them there either, because...

**what is saved to the database:**

```
{
    "id": "object768f02af46b24a5c86c1e5eeaae721c6",
    "_rid": "9ikLAL9mDQATAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/9ikLAA==/colls/9ikLAL9mDQA=/docs/9ikLAL9mDQATAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000200-0000-0000-0000-5a1bed1c0000\"",
    "family_name": "Green",
    "given_name": "Thomas",
    "phone_numbers": [
        {
            "id": "eb8e6d6b6317499c96c568a2b6088101",
            "_rid": null,
            "_self": null,
            "_ts": 0,
            "_etag": null,
            "name": "private phone",
            "number": "564894654"
        },
        {
            "id": "e8ffb8de9d55489cb84d3342189240c1",
            "_rid": null,
            "_self": null,
            "_ts": 0,
            "_etag": null,
            "name": "work phone",
            "number": "654649684684"
        }
    ],
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1511779612
}
```

...the correct meta-tags for the root object are created upon writing into DocumentDB. Great. But the meta-tags in the child documents are emtpy. I don't need them and obviously DocumentDB does not need them either.

**what i ultimately want to be saved to the database instead:**

```
{
    "id": "object768f02af46b24a5c86c1e5eeaae721c6",
    "_rid": "9ikLAL9mDQATAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/9ikLAA==/colls/9ikLAL9mDQA=/docs/9ikLAL9mDQATAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00000200-0000-0000-0000-5a1bed1c0000\"",
    "family_name": "Green",
    "given_name": "Thomas",
    "phone_numbers": [
        {
            "id": "eb8e6d6b6317499c96c568a2b6088101",
            "name": "private phone",
            "number": "564894654"
        },
        {
            "id": "e8ffb8de9d55489cb84d3342189240c1",
            "name": "work phone",
            "number": "654649684684"
        }
    ],
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1511779612
}
```

I find it difficult to find information on things related to DocumentDB, the internal workings of `Microsoft.Azure.Documents` and am lacking knowledge of the correct terms, so pointers in that direction will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.document?view=azure-dotnet) states that it

> Represents a document in the Azure Cosmos DB service.

It is a special subtype of [Resource class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.documents.resource?view=azure-dotnet) and as such it contains the meta-properties that all DocumentDB resource-level objects need.

In your case, by trying to suppress it's Resource-behavior, you are trying to use the type for a scenario it is not intended for. That's always a warning sign to reconsider your design.

Still, what you could do:

**Alternative 1: remove default values during serialization**

The fields you don't want are using the default values. You can omit such fields from serialized JSON if you want to. You can serialize with custom settings using `Document.SaveTo(Stream, SerializationFormattingPolicy, JsonSerializerSettings)` method.

Note that it would also affect other fields in your model with default values. this may or may not be what you want.

**Alternative 2: custom model classes**

You could consider defining a strongly typed explicit storage model which already contains only the properties you want stored and necessary translation logic between them or to other models. If you don't need those meta-fields then don't include them.

**Alternative 3: JObject**

You could consider working on [Newtonsoft's JObject type](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) instead.

This is just as flexible as `Document`, but it would give you full control of the JSON that would end up in your document. Just explicitly remove any undesired phone-number item meta-properties before saving your aggregated document to DocumentDB.

Comment: "That's always a warning sign to reconsider your design."... my spider-sense was tickling but as I stated in my question it's a bit hard to find digestible information on this. I couldn't even find an appropriate tag for "documentdb" here on stackoverflow, only azure-cosmosdb even though this is not strictly Cosmosdb-related. Anyway, great answer and exactly the kind of advice I need at this point! Thank you.